# Не фиксировать определенный option в select

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Мой селект обрабатывается js. Как только человек выбирает "выбрать другой", всплывают дополнительные окна выбора (как на авито выбор города). Одна проблема : как при выборе этой опции сделать так, чтобы она не переходила в состояние selected ? Спасибо

```html
<select id="region" name="location_id" class="js-search-form-region">
 <option value="621540" data-parent-id="" selected="">По всей России</option><option value="625500">Молочное</option><option value="625480">Красавино</option><option value="637640" data-parent-id="621540" data-metro-map="1">Москва</option><option value="653240" data-parent-id="621540" data-metro-map="1">Санкт-Петербург</option><option value="624840" data-parent-id="624770">Волгоград</option><option value="654070" data-parent-id="653700">Екатеринбург</option><option value="650400" data-parent-id="650130">Казань</option><option value="633540" data-parent-id="632660">Краснодар</option><option value="640860" data-parent-id="640310">Нижний Новгород</option><option value="641780" data-parent-id="641470">Новосибирск</option><option value="642320" data-parent-id="642020">Омск</option><option value="644200" data-parent-id="643700">Пермь</option><option value="652000" data-parent-id="651110">Ростов-на-Дону</option><option value="653040" data-parent-id="652560">Самара</option><option value="646600" data-parent-id="645790">Уфа</option><option value="661420" data-parent-id="660710">Челябинск</option> <option value="0">Выбрать другой...</option> </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам придется сохранять предыдущее значение, например вот так

`$("#region").data("oldvalue", $("#region").val());`

А когда в обработчике `change` Вы выясните, что значение меняться не должно, делаете

`$("#region").val($("#region").data("oldvalue"));`